# How to convert/cast (at bit level) Struct from other with the same size?

Tags: c#

suppose I have two 128-bit structures ...

```
struct OldInfo
{
    int  Id,
    int  Tag,
    long Code
}

struct NewInfo
{
    short Kind,
    long  Key,
    int   Data,
    short Value
}
```

and then I want to...

```
var old = new OldInfo();
. . .
var new = (NewInfo)old;   // Cast bit by bit as they have same size
```

So, how to cast (at bit level) on struct from another of same size, fast?
Maybe using some bitwise operation? or 'unsafe'? or aplying 'StructLayout' attribute?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you could try to cast it within `unsafe` block

Comment: There is no copy-with-truncation in C#, nor is there anything similar.

Comment: Marshal.Copy and Marshal.StructureToPtr, PtrToStructure methods can be used for that

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit You can't `Marshal.Copy` on a struct, because it is a value type. You could use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure` (and remember to free the memory with) but you are using an intermediate buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written the two structures don't have the same size. This because the `NewInfo.Key` is a `long` so normally is aligned on 8 byte boundary... So there is a "gap" of 6 empty bytes between `Kind` and `Key` (you can try doing a `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NewInfo))`). But you can apply a `[StructLayout]` attribute to fix this.

```
struct OldInfo
{
    public int Id;
    public int Tag;
    public long Code;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto, Pack = 1)]
struct NewInfo
{
    public short Kind;
    public long Key;
    public int Data;
    public short Value;
}
```

Now... There is a totally unsafe [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) library of Microsoft:

```
int s1 = Unsafe.SizeOf<OldInfo>();
int s2 = Unsafe.SizeOf<NewInfo>();
Debug.Assert(s1 == s2);

OldInfo oi = new OldInfo { Id = 1, Tag = 2, Code = 3 } ;
NewInfo ni = Unsafe.As<OldInfo, NewInfo>(ref oi);
```

This library is unsafe enough that it won't tell you if the size of the structures are different :-) It will copy and perhaps overwrite something important in memory :-)